# How to generate a snapshot of a field in a time step with VTK and Python

Tags: python, numpy, vtk, openfoam

I am working with the `cavity` example of the OpenFoam installation (v1812). After executing it (`icoFoam`) having the following result:

```
$ ls
0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  constant  system
```

I would like to know if it is possible to postprocess the time steps, through a script, that generated a matrix of pixels with the values of a given field (for instance the pressure).

Apart from the array (which could be handled with numpy) of each time step, I'd also like to show as a result a heat map like this:

[image]

Comment: Assuming you don't want to use OpenFOAM's internal utilities, but only NumPy: [ofpp](https://github.com/dayigu/ofpp) is a light parser converting OpenFOAM fields into NumPy arrays. If you would like to use OpenFOAM's utilities, I need to post an answer, yet there are plenty, such as `runTimePostProcessing`, `sample surfaces` and so on. Additionally, you can do `VTK` scripting for ParaView+OpenFOAM.

Comment: I do not mind to use OpenFOAM's utilities. Nevertheless, I'll also check OFPP. Thank you.

Comment: `ofpp` should do help you, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example of post processing of the `cavity` example [here](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/blob/master/vedo/examples/volumetric/streamlines3.py) using [vedo](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by function objects also. By writing and extracting data you need at each time step, you could have as many as data you like. By using `pyFoam` or any other python code, you could use it as arrays. First try search for `functionObjects`.